# Why is DateTime passed to a CRM action 6 hours less than what I pass in?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have an action that takes in two required DateTime fields, `StartDate` and `EndDate`. From the API, when I invoke this action those fields are passed as follows:

`{
    "StartDate":"2018-07-01T00:00:00Z",
    "EndDate":"2019-06-30T00:00:00Z"
}`

However, when they hit the action I get the following result right as I debug the input parameters:

`Start Date - 6/30/2018 6:00 PM | End Date - 6/29/2019 6:00 PM`

So the start date has gone from 7/1/2018 midnight to 6/30/2018 6PM and end date has gone from 6/30/2019 midnight to 6/29/2019 6PM. I ensured that our API is passing the correct data and confirmed that there are no additional workflows/actions/plugins that might modify this date.

Why is this date adjusting by 6 hours?

Comment: Timezone issue? The Z at the end of the string means UTC. Would you by any chance be 6 hours west of UTC?

Comment: Hmm, I am in California. That's UTC-7 though right? Since that seems to be the case, what are the recommended practices when dealing with WebAPI calls to Dynamics and setting DateTime? I would imagine we should have some sort of uniformity in how it is set.

Comment: @fvu After discussing it with the team, seems like our fields need to be adjusted to have the behavior of DateOnly. Unfortunately, that is very hard to do after the fact. Is there another approach to this?

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to "debug the input parameters", i.e. the code that produces this output:  `Start Date - 6/30/2018 6:00 PM | End Date - 6/29/2019 6:00 PM`?

Comment: That's actually just a simple assign value step where I just take the input parameters and concatenate them into a string. Then I pass that string off to an activity that calls tracer.trace(message). Nothing too fancy there.

Comment: just an addition comment, I had this issue/challenge occurring lot of times playing with dates and it has to be dealt with care and some thought processing how you want to handle dates in Your code.
As mentioned by others it is clearly difference between Server Time in UTC and user Local Time in UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be a time zone conversion. When you intercept date time on the server it has been converted to UTC.

[Behavior and format of the date and time attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/behavior-format-date-time-attribute).

I imagine your dates are user local (default), which will:

> - Stores the date and time value as UTC value in the system.
> - The retrieve operation returns the UTC value.

When you retrieve the value programmatically you will need to convert the value back to your local time zone to get the original value you put in, the CRM user interface does this.

You could switch your field to date only or time zone independent if that behaviour better suits your use case. You could do this programmatically if you have a lot of fields to update.